# Trying to create an accordion which remains readable

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion with a huge amount of text inside that remains readable.

I found this useful function, but it has a problem - if the user reloads the page it doesn't work anymore.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.eael-accordion-header').click(function() {
    var pane = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      var $panel = pane.closest('.eael-accordion-list');
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $panel.offset().top - 100
      }, 500);
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

I have tried changing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... })
```

by

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function($) { ... })
```

But if I do that, the code doesn't works anymore and it says that `$ is not a function`.

I really hate jQuery, because I don't understand it at all. How can I translate this function into plain JavaScript, please?

Comment: Try here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Translating that jQuery code in to plain JS will a) involve completely re-writing the jQuery animation engine, which is a large chunk of the jQuery source, and not easy b) not fix your underlying 'refresh breaking the accordion' problem. I'd suggest you debug to determine the cause of the accordion not working on refresh and attempting to fix that. We can help you debug it if you add a working example of the issue to the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers! I see... I thought that it would be easier to translate that code into plain JavaScript. As I said, I don’t understand jQuery at all. I’m not sure about how to add a working example to the question, Rory. Anyway I’ll try to debug what’s could be creating this issue. Thanks again. Regards.